# Modifying a variable in another shell script

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I am trying to modify the variables of one shell script, using another script. This is what I have so far:

**script1.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

var=123.45.67.890
```

**script2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

currVar=000.00.00.000

. /./script1.sh
var=$currVar
```

I understand that I am not modifying Script 1 here, but simply temporarily modifying var. How can I modify this var in script 1, via script 2?

**Solution**

```
. /./script1.sh
echo $var | sed "s/$var/$currVar/g" /./script1.sh > "temp.txt" && mv temp.txt /./script1.sh
```

Comment: Question is very vague, may I know as to why you're doing this?

Comment: I'm just trying to automate a process, by being able to change IP addresses on demand using script writing.

Comment: Maybe you can write the entire description in the question and I can suggest an answer or alternative?

Comment: there isn't really much more to the question, I am just wondering if this is possible and if so, what is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: @sartar, do you know about positional parameters, i.e. `$1`, `$2`, etc? Or parameter expansion, i.e. `${var:-foo}` ?  Or "command substitution", i.e. `$(...)`? Any of these might help you solve this problem better than the solution you've appended to your question. *NOTE*: This is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You're asking for a way to implement the solution you have in mind, not to solve your underlying problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `sed` in `2nd` script (`script2.sh`) as

```
currVar="000.00.00.000"
sed -r -i.bak "s/var=([[:graph:]]+)/var=$currVar/" script1.sh
var=000.00.00.000
```

where `[[:graph:]]` is a character class for `[[:alnum:]]` & `[[:punct:]]` to match values for `var` with printable characters/meta-characters.

Since you mentioned it is a proper IP address, use a proper `regEx` as

```
sed -r "s/(\b[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b/$currVar/" script1.sh
var=000.00.00.000
```

`(\b[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}` implies match `3` groups consisting of digits from `0-9`, which each group could have from `1-3` digits each, preceded by a dot `.` and the 4th group also the same as the last. Remember the each group I am mentioning represents an IP octet

Comment: Maybe you can modify var=000 with var='$currVar'.

Comment: @sartar. yes it will. you have just to change Inian's script with ....var='$currVar'...

Comment: sudo sh 'script2.sh'

Comment: the variables are not changing in script 1 for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Normally, variables in scripts have local scope. If you `export` the variable, you can extend this scope to include any child processes. However, it looks like you might want to use the modified value when `script1.sh` runs. If that is the case, you can use the new var value as an input to `script1.sh` when you run it.

```
if [[ -z "$1" ]];
then
  var=$1
else
  var=123.45.67.890
```

This will check if you gave any parameters when you ran `script1.sh`, and if you did, then it should set your `var` equal to this value instead of the default IP.

Comment: I figured it out, solution in question, what do you think?

Comment: @sartar: Even if its working, its a not-so-pretty way to do the job, refer my solution.

Comment: Saying that exporting makes a variable global is mis-leading.  The variable is not global, it is copied to any child processes.  Global would imply shared data - if the child alters its own environment variables it will not affect the parent.